# Left-align text with `visual-line-mode` and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode`

Tags: wrapping, visual-line-mode

When I use `visual-line-mode` in conjunction with `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode`, the wrapped text is not perfectly left-aligned (i.e. the text is not on a straight edge). Instead, it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` properly left-align the first word of each new line?

Thanks!